# Lazy-loading issue while implementing jQuery DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, datatable

I'm getting the "*The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection*" error message on my intranet app when I try to implement a jQuery DataTable for a relational SQL database.

This is my HomeController code:

```
using CyberAssets.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CyberAssets.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult loaddata()
        {
            using (CyberAssetsEntities dc = new CyberAssetsEntities())
            {
                var data = dc.CyberAssets.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToList();
                return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my View with the DataTable:

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DataTbl').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/loaddata",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "FacilityName", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "FacilityType", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "MachineType", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "MachineFunctionDesc", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "PhysicalLocation", "autowidth": true }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

How can I preload the objects that I need to refer to within the `loaddata()` `using` block in my HomeController and basically "avoid" lazy-loading?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following lines to your DataTable initialization code:

```
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
```

So you code for DataTable should look like this:

```
$('#DataTbl').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Home/loaddata",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "FacilityName", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "FacilityType", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "MachineType", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "MachineFunctionDesc", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "PhysicalLocation", "autowidth": true }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: @ScopeY Well, it looks like your EntityFramework database context object has been disposed. Which line in your code produces the error?

Comment: I actually managed to fix the error. Just a minor tweak type thing. I appreciate your help, though.